# Docker Swarm mode with Ubuntu and Mac

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm-mode

I ran  `docker swarm init` on master node

Then ran `docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-xxxx 192.168.1.105:2377` from worker nodes.

I have total 5 nodes (3 Ubuntu, 2 mac)

I deploy by `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose-worker.yml --with-registry-auth PL`

The command above starts up a container in each node.

However `docker network inspect PL_default` shows only 3 peers(all ubuntu).
The 2 nodes can't ping the master or any other node using the ip listed under `Containers`

```
    "Containers": {
        "ba41b64a7023beda84083b728194abb882d04eaf23057e7ee8ace698d1e4f7cf": {
            "Name": "PL_spark-worker.1.ntq6o5ynuq1qjzpu16dkd81i1",
            "EndpointID": "c6c76b074afb13a72dbbff23c504bb4e7013c70dfbdad6958ff0caebc00da109",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:02:26",
            "IPv4Address": "10.0.2.38/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "cf35c1ac8e3e81e5d78219ae5d1903bc21728e1e55c6fdea6da56777a2c6c963": {
            "Name": "PL_spark-master.1.cx9nlup5jmr8u9eqal99g67p4",
            "EndpointID": "e847acc5c89a058157a513972b3fcf3e2558a25a7dcabcfc70fb5a1c8d08b914",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:02:25",
            "IPv4Address": "10.0.2.37/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "lb-PL_default": {
            "Name": "PL_default-endpoint",
            "EndpointID": "b1269a5f1aad5228254e5de69fe96a5b96e52313c6f18c174ce12357264001b7",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:02:04",
            "IPv4Address": "10.0.2.4/24",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Peers": [
        {
            "Name": "8a91513fec15",
            "IP": "192.168.1.105"
        },
        {
            "Name": "fb24a4880049",
            "IP": "192.168.1.104"
        },
        {
            "Name": "f9775403a53f",
            "IP": "192.168.1.100"
        }
    ]
```

Where should I look?

- edit

> Per-container IP addressing is not possible The docker (Linux) bridge
>   network is not reachable from the macOS host

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

What does the above line mean?  Does it mean you can't connect to docker on linux from docker on macOS ?